# How can I check if there's element in my arraylist that is not in the hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<String>` in `java` and it contains some Strings.

I also have a `hashmap` with `String` values and I would like to check if there's any element in my List that is not in the Hashmap. This is the code I wrote:

```
List<String> someStrings = fetchData();
if (someStrings.stream().noneMatch(s -> myHashMap.containsValue(s))) {
    return false;
} 
return true;
```

But it does not work properly. Can you help me with that?

Comment: please provide HashMap object type<?>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that your condition is

> if there's any element in my List that is not in the Hashmap

you can use `anyMatch` while iterating over the list of elements to check if any of them is not present in the hashmap values.

```
return someStrings.stream().anyMatch(val -> !myHashMap.containsValue(val))
```

---

Or to look at it as if ***all elements of `someStrings` are present in hashmap values***

```
return someStrings.stream().allMatch(myHashMap::containsValue);
```

A similar check though could also be using `containsAll` over the `Collection` of values :

```
return myHashMap.values().containsAll(someStrings);
```

Comment: thank you, I like the `containsAll` approach, I just noticed that it doesn't work when there's one empty string added to `someStrings` (`containsAll` seems to return true in that case, even though I don't have an empty value in my hashmap). Do you know how to prevent it?

Comment: @randomuser1 Well if you mean `var someStrings = List.of("", "alpha","beta")` and `var mapValues = List.of("alpha","beta")`, then it would certainly return `false`. I can confirm testing it.

Comment: could you try `List.of("");`?

Comment: Keep in mind that `someStrings.stream().anyMatch(val -> !myHashMap.containsValue(val))` is the opposite of `myHashMap.values().containsAll(someStrings)`…

Comment: @randomuser1 if you meant the `someStrings` as `List.of("")`, tested that as well. Could you edit the question and elaborate on the test case you're testing it with?

Comment: @Holger When would that be so? The intention I'd put that up was to ensure that all the elements of the list `someStrings` are present in the `values` of the hashmap. If any of them is not present, it should return `false`.

Comment: @nullpointer In one case you check whether all the values in your someStrings are inside the hashset, in the other you check the opposite. Also depending on the implementation of containsAll the performance would obviously be very different.

Comment: @Voo In both the cases I am checking if all `someStrings` elements are included in the hashmap `values`, that's what puzzled me with Holger's comment as well.

Comment: You can read your code literally, `anyMatch(val -> !myHashMap.containsValue(val))` checks if **any** element is **not** **contain**ed in the **value**s. Which is the opposite of whether all are contained. Which is, of course, a viable test using the process of elimination. It’s just delivering the opposite value, so a `!` before the entire expression would produce the same value. Or just using `allMatch(val -> myHashMap.containsValue(val))`, which now, without the negation, can be written as `allMatch(myHashMap::containsValue)` or `allMatch(myHashMap.values()::contains)`…

Comment: @Holger Alright, I got the point of comparison between `all` Vs `any` with the return type. Its just that I was assuming the value returned would be used accordingly, but ya correct `allMatch` is equivalent to `containsAll` check. Updated. Thanks for such elaboration. Its always good to get those review comments.

Comment: Well yes, these are two sides of the same test and you could use either result accordingly, but since the OP seemed to be confused about the result regarding `List.of("")`, I just wanted to leave a reminder about the opposite values, to ensure that the OP did not overlook that small detail when testing.

Answer (score 7):

No need for streams, you can just use the good old `Collection#removeAll()`:

```
Set<String> copy = new HashSet<>(someStrings);
copy.removeAll(myHashMap.values());
```

Now `copy` will contain all the values not contained in `myHashMap`. You can then do something with them (like iterating) or just call `Collection#isEmpty()` to check if all are contained in the map